# MS-Project 2010 - How to add Task Name to the Quick Access ribbon?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I used to love the fact that there was a text editing box at the top of the screen in old versions of MS-P, allowing you to edit Task Name directly without having to open the Task Information dialog. This is so useful when setting up a project as the wording continually changes and also to allow quick entry of tasks...

I know it can be done in MS-Project 2010, I have done it in the past- You can add the Task Name field to the Quick Access ribbon and it operates exactly as it used to. But I cannot, for the life of me, remember how I did it.

I have been through the Customise Quick Access Ribbon screens and cannot find anything relevant and I have visited the fields in Task Information to see if a right-click gives me the ability to add to the ribbon, but to no avail.

I have a massive plan to set up, with many 100s of tasks, and it is driving me crazy that I have to go into each Task Information just to amend some text as I am organising the tasks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on 'File' tab, select 'Options'.

The 'Project Options' dialogue window will open.

Select 'Display'.  Check the 'Entry Bar' option.

Answer (score 2):

Also F2 drops you into edit mode if the clicking twice doesn't work for you.
Previous releases had the Entry Bar enabled by default. You can display it in later releases through File, Options. However I had to turn off my edit bar due to some repeated profile corruption in Project.

Answer (score 1):

Typical. As soon as I post the question I realise the answer... You can edit the tasks names in-line directly within the Gantt Chart grid by clicking into the field and then clicking again. How did I miss that?!

Answer (score -1):

File>Options
Display option
Click "Entry bar" check box

Comment: Hi & welcome to PMSE. Have a look on the [tour] page to see how this site works.
Could you add some more words to your answer to improve readability and understandability?